# Create a simple range/values in range table

Tags: r

I am working on a simple project to help me get to know R, coming from javascript.
I have imported a list of numbers, and all I simply want to do, is to export a table that looks like the following:

```
"range","number" 
"0.000-0.510",863
"0.510-1.020",21
"1.020-1.530",2
"1.530-2.040",2
"2.040-2.550",0
"2.550-3.059",2
"3.059-3.569",0
"3.569-4.079",3
"4.079->4.589",0
"4.589->5.099",1
```

where the ranges are in 10 steps, from the smallest to the largest value, the "range" and "number" are the top rows, and the columns going down are the different ranges and number of occurrences in this range.

This is my attempt so far:

```
list <- read.csv(file = "results/solarSystem.data")
table(list)

range <- (max(list) - min(list)) / 10

a1<-as.data.frame(table(cut(list,breaks=c(min(list),min(list)+1*range,min(list)+2*range,min(list)+3*range,min(list)+4*range,min(list)+5*range,min(list)+6*range,min(list)+7*range,min(list)+8*range,min(list)+9*range,max(list)))))

colnames(a1)<-c("range","freq")

a1
```

However, I get an error that

> 'Error in cut.default(list, breaks = c(min(list), min(list) + 1 * range...
> 'x' must be numeric'

This is the file I am importing, what looks like just a simple list of numbers, so I don't understand how it cannot be numeric?
https://gyazo.com/8fd00ce45c1c033f9dc9bf6c829195eb
Any advice on this would be appreciated!
Peter

Comment: Hi, A random list of numbers (`list <- rnorm(20)*20`) gives the output you're want.  Could your "list of numbers" have a non-numeric character?  e.g. a comma. If you use `readr::read_csv()` instead of `read.csv()`, then it will give a summary of the imported content, which might highlight the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! the readr:: doesn't seem to show any other characters other than a space in between each character. I think perhaps my 'list' of numbers is being imported as a string with spaces/linebreaks in between each of the values. Is there a way to use something like as.numeric() to turn them into numerical data?

Comment: Yes, using `list <- as.numeric(list)` should convert them to values.  Any that are not convertible will be highlighted and help you understand where the problem is.  I'm guessing a little, as I don't have the data to play with.  Good luck.